# Firefox plugin doesn't load data?

Tags: firefox, plugins, jpeg2000

I have some JPEG2000 images that I'd like to make available on the web.  I'm planning to use the LizardTech ExpressView browser plugin to do this.  (It's at http://www.lizardtech.com/downloads/category/#plugins.)  They provide some instructions for including the necessary HTML to display the plugin in both IE and Firefox.  It works for me in IE, but not in Firefox; there, the following HTML just shows the ExpressView plugin with no image loaded into it.

```
<object vspace="10" name width="600" height="500"
    classid="CLSID:2513AB48-1AEF-4E55-8329-927FF97C9DCE"
    codebase="http://www.lizardtech.com/plugin/MrSID_BPI.cab#Version=5,0,1">
    <param name="imgSource"
        value="http://localhost/relax.jp2" />
    <object width="600" height="600" autostart="true" type="image/x-mrsid-image" data="http://localhost/relax.jp2">
        <param name="imgSource" value="http://localhost/relax.jp2" />
    </object>
</object>
```

My understanding is that the outer object definition is what IE uses, and the inner one is what Firefox uses.  I don't know if this might be helpful, but when I look at the network tab in Firefox's developer tools when I load the page, it does request relax.jp2, but it apparently returns zero bytes for some reason.  Does anyone know what the proper syntax is?  I also eventually want to include a link to download the plugin if the user doesn't have it, but I assume that won't be difficult to do.  Thanks!

EDIT: Cleaned up the code paste; sorry about that.

Comment: `image/x-mrsid-[lotsofspaces]image` is not exactly a valid mime-type...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox was getting a return code of 206 when requesting relax.jp2.  It turns out that using the correct mime type is important!  Instead of x-mrsid-image, I used image/jpeg2000, and the image loads into the plugin correctly, since the ExpressView plugin is registered for that type as well.